# Framework's public class appearing in a new created iOS project but not in existing iOS project

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I have create a Framework which contains a swift public class named as 'SDKManager'. 
When I have added this framework into a new created iOS app, this class available in it. And this framework work properly.

But whenever I have added this framework in existing iOS App project, 'SDKManager' class not appearing in this project. Framework module available in this project but its classes not.

Comment: Try to compare the project settings of the two projects. If the project is really old it might not have the necessary build settings set that are necessary for swift code usage/compile (several swift sections). Normally Xcode ask for project migration when using newer Xcode versions to fix this, maybe there is something broken in your project. In that case you should create a new project file from scratch and add your necessary build settings and source code again. If you do so you should also think about build setting extraction into xcconfig files. That makes project recreations much easier.

Comment: thank you @rmaddy. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Wasn't my suggestion. You should reply to @codealchimist